# exporting expressions to C, part 1 [wolfram-mathematica]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have several expressions I have generated in Mathematica that I would like to export into the source code of an external C program.  "CForm" almost does what I want except that exponentiation is expressed as calls to `Power()`.  My expressions involves only small powers so I would prefer that the expression in C use inlined multiplication rather than a call to `Power()`.

For example `CForm[2 hgt^2 k1inv^3 mx0 wid^2 + hgt^2 k1inv^3 wid^3]` yields

`2*Power(hgt,2)*Power(k1inv,3)*mx0*Power(wid,2) + 
   Power(hgt,2)*Power(k1inv,3)*Power(wid,3)`

..whereas what I would like to generate is:

`2*hgt*hgt*k1inv*k1inv*k1inv*mx0*wid*wid + 
   hgt*hgt*k1inv*k1inv*k1inv*wid*wid*wid`

My initial attempts to pick out the internal `Power[..]` parts of the expression and remap it to a multiplication using `x_Symbol^y_Integer /; y > 1 :> Fold[Times, 1, Table[#1, {#2}]]` have been stymied by mathematica immediately converting my carefully generated sub expressions `a*a*a` right back into `Power[a,3]` ;-)  I know it is only trying to help but I can't figure out how to ask it to stop, in this case...

As I have written this question it has occurred to me that I could capture the output of `CForm` into a string and then perform string pattern matching and manipulation on that, but is that a good way to go?  I think I prefer to work on it as a Mathematica expression as I do my remapping and then output..?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the case at hand, you may use something like the following:

```
Clear[getCFormNoPowers];
getCFormNoPowers[expr_] :=
  Module[{times},      
   Apply[Function[code, Hold[CForm[code]], HoldAll],
     Hold[#] &[expr /. x_Symbol^y_Integer /; y > 1 :> 
         times @@ Table[x, {y}]] /. times -> Times]];
```

For example,

```
In[52]:= getCFormNoPowers[2 hgt^2 k1inv^3 mx0 wid^2+hgt^2 k1inv^3 wid^3]

Out[52]= Hold[2*mx0*(hgt*hgt)*(wid*wid)*(k1inv*k1inv*k1inv) + 
hgt*hgt*(k1inv*k1inv*k1inv)* (wid*wid*wid)]
```

The result is wrapped in `Hold`, to prevent its evaluation back to `Power`-s. You can convert it to 
a string at any time, using something like `ToString[HoldForm@@result]`. Or you can manipulate is further.

Edit:

as an alternative, you can do this:

```
Clear[getCFormNoPowers];
getCFormNoPowers[expr_] :=
 Block[{Times},
   SetAttributes[Times, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
   Apply[Function[code, Hold[CForm[code]], HoldAll],
   Hold[#] &[expr /. x_Symbol^y_Integer /; y > 1 :> Times @@ Table[x, {y}]]]];
```

which will also keep the original order of your terms and will get rid of unnecessary parentheses, so this one seem to correspond precisely to your specs.

Generally, you may want to have a look at the new "symbolic C generation" capabilities of the version 8. Mapping your code to symbolic C expressions may be a more robust approach. In that way, you don't have to worry about evaluation all the time, and you may use the new functionality to generate entire C programs at the end.

Edit 2:

To illustrate how the problem can be solved with the SymbolicC:

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"];

Clear[getCFormNoPowersSymC];
getCFormNoPowersSymC[expr_] :=
  Block[{Times},
   SetAttributes[Times, {Flat, Orderless}];
   ToCCodeString[
     expr /. x_Symbol^y_Integer /; y > 1 :> Times @@ Table[x, {y}] //.     
       HoldPattern[(op : (Times | Plus))[args__]] :>  COperator[op, {args}]]];

In[53]:= getCFormNoPowersSymC[2 hgt^2 k1inv^3 mx0 wid^2+hgt^2 k1inv^3 wid^3]

Out[53]= 2 * hgt * hgt * k1inv * k1inv * k1inv * mx0 * wid * wid + 
    hgt * hgt * k1inv * k1inv * k1inv * wid * wid * wid
```

This method IMO has several advantages. Perhaps the two main ones being composability (one can nest such expressions in their symbolic form, building larger blocks of code from smaller ones), and the fact that one does not have to think much about evaluation (I didn't need any tricks with `Hold` here).

Comment: Thanks for a nice meaty answer, I am still puzzling through many of its subtleties (e.g. why the `HoldAll` for `CForm?` Neatly using `times` but then changing to `Times` outside the `Hold`.  And the undocumented(?) use of `HoldAll` as an argument to `Apply`)

Comment: I actually removed the `HoldAll`, it is unnecessary. See also another solution with `Block`. The possibility of adding Attributes to pure functions is documented at the `Function` page, the last item under the "more information" section there. The undocumented use would be if I used `Function[Null,Hold[CForm[#]],HoldAll]`. What is IMO the most interesting part here is that `CForm` works inside `Hold`. So, like other forms, it is not the usual command but rather the special mode of representing the output.

Comment: That is an interesting behaviour from CForm; if I copy the output and then paste into a notebook it seems to be a string value inside Hold e.g. `Hold["2 hgt hgt k1inv k1inv k1inv mx0 wid wid + hgt hgt k1inv k1inv k1inv wid wid wid"]` and yet pasting the same copy buffer into a text editor or doing a `Fullform` shows that it is being held `Hold[CForm[2 hgt hgt k1inv k1inv k1inv mx0 wid wid + hgt hgt k1inv k1inv k1inv wid wid wid]]`; odd, but the documentation of CForm does warn that it is a clever synatical sugarcoat only.  BTW thank you very much for your help this has solved my problem.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin I have been looking at the "symbolic C generation" capabilities of 8, but other than the ability to _represent_ a c program in Mathematica and perhaps to describe it parametrically, so that you can quickly generate many versions of the same program, I haven't got a clue how to use it in a sensible way. And, getting back to the question, I don't see how it can be used to replace CForm. I can imagine that you could write a replacement of CForm in terms of Symbolic C concepts, but that's _work_ and I want Mathematica to do that for me.

Comment: @Sjoerd Frankly, I haven' t used it much yet. But in this particular case, it is not too difficult and the code size is about the same (see the edit to my post), while this can also serve as a building block for building larger programs, so one can accumulate one's own functions like this, eventually turning them into some mini-compiler to C for a small subset of Mathematica, suited to one's individual needs.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Nice! I begin to see how this may become useful. Perhaps we should start a question about Symbolic C to generate ideas about its uses. There's nothing on that in the docs AFAIK.

Comment: @Sjoerd Separate discussion on symbolic C sounds like a good idea! As for its usefulness, AFAIK the compilation to C functionality is just one  of its heavy users, there may be others. Together with the CCompilerDriver and LibraryLink they form a complete cycle to generate C code from within Mathematica, compile it, optionally link it with some external libraries and and plug it back into the kernel. The documentation is quite brief indeed, I hope it will be improved in future releases.